# Peticiones POST Y GET API REST

Tags: html, python, json, post, get

Estoy haciendo una petición POST a una web para que me facilite el token, y su respuesta a sido ok, código 200.

```
    import requests

url = 'https://datadis.es/nikola-auth/tokens/login'
data = {'username': 'XXXXXXXXX', 'password': 'XXXXXXXXX'}

response = requests.post(url, data=data)
token = response.content
print(response.content)

headers = {'Authorization': token} #{'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'}
params = {'authorizedNif': 'XXXXXXX', 'distributorCode': '2'}

response = requests.get('https://datadis.es/api-private/api/get-supplies', headers=headers, params=params)
print(response.json())
```

Pero cuando solicita un GET me da error 401 desautorizado, no se que estoy haciendo mal, os pongo el código y una captura de pantalla.

Comment: Lo único que puedo mencionar es que el `token`  normalmente se pasa tal como lo tienes comentado `Bearer {token}`

Comment: En el código que publicas estas realizando una petición GET, te sugiero muestres el código de como realizas tanto la petición POST como GET, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno lo solucioné de esta manera.

```
    import requests

# Obtiene el token de autenticación para el área privada. petición POST
url_login = "https://datadis.es/nikola-auth/tokens/login"
payload_login = {'username': '3XXXXXX', 'password': 'XXXXX'}

# Realizar la petición POST y obtener el token
response_login = requests.post(url_login, data=payload_login)

token = response_login.text

# Buscar todos los suministros, petición GET
url_get = "https://datadis.es/api-private/api/get-supplies"
payload_get = {'authorizedNif': 'XXXXXX', 'distributorCode': 'E-distribución'}
headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'}

# Realizar la petición GET con el token obtenido
response_get = requests.get(url_get, params=payload_get, headers=headers)
print(response_get.json())
```

cogí del json el valor text.  `token = response_login.text` para enviar en la cabecera del get y funcionó, ahora el problema que me da es este error, se ve que recibo datos del servidor pero no imprime en pantalla el formato json, este es el error:

```
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: El error de JsonDecodeError suele ser porque se intenta decodificar un json como array, pero este json esta mal formado (o no es un json). dado que te da un error al imprimir el response_get codificado a json... prueba a imprimir otro metodo, para ver que te esta devolviendo, no vaya a ser que te devuelva un html (por ej)

Comment: Correcto llevas razón, no me estaba dando un json, en cuanto lo he corregido todo OK, graciassss